# Most common sublist in Prolog

Tags: list, algorithm, prolog, sublist

The problem is as follows: Write a predicate in Prolog most_common_sublist(L1,N,L2) that will find the sublist L2 with length N such that it is the most common sublist in L1.

```
//Example 1:
?- most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],1,L).
L=[2];

//Example 2:
?- most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],2,L).
L=[2,2];

//Example 3:
?- most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],3,L).
L=[2,2,3];
```

My approach was to generate all the possible sublists of size N using the generator predicate, check which of those is the most common one in the list using the check predicate, and then just put that as my result.
The reason why I'm not using the built-in predicates for length and add is because I'm supposed to write my own.
My generator predicate works, it gives out the correct output.

```
?- generator([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],3,L).
L = [[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2], [2, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2], [4, 2|...], [2|...]] [write]
L = [[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2], [2, 2, 4], [2, 4, 2], [4, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]]
```

I checked all my predicates and they all seem to work (at least for the test cases I'm using), the problem occurs with the check predicate. It seems to work fine until it gets to N>=P (when this is NOT true, works fine when it is true). I expect the program to go onto the next check predicate under it (the third check predicate) so that it stores Temp value in Result instead of the H value. For some reason it does not go to the third check predicate (I checked with debugger), instead it does something weird (I can't figure out what).

```
most_common_sublist(L,N,Result):-generator(L,N,LOP),check(LOP,_,Temp),add(Temp,[],Result).

add([],L,L).
add([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-add(L1,L2,L3).

length([],0).
length([X|O],N):-length(O,M),N is M+1.

sublist([H|_],1,[H]).
sublist([H|T],N,[H|LOP]):-M is N-1,sublist(T,M,LOP).

generator(L,N,[L]):-length(L,M),N=:=M.
generator([H|T],N,LOP):-sublist([H|T],N,PN),generator(T,N,LP),add([PN],LP,LOP).

check([],Z,K):-Z is 0,add([],[],K).
check([H|T],Hits,Result):-check_how_many(H,[H|T],N),check(T,P,_),N>=P,Hits is N,add(H,[],Result).
check([H|T],Hits,Result):-check_how_many(H,[H|T],N),check(T,P,Temp),Hits is P,add(Temp,[],Result).

check_how_many(X,[X],1).
check_how_many(_,[_],0).
check_how_many(Pattern,[H|T],Hits):-same(Pattern,H),check_how_many(Pattern,T,P),Hits is P+1.
check_how_many(Pattern,[_|T],Hits):-check_how_many(Pattern,T,P),Hits is P.

same([], []).
same([H1|R1], [H2|R2]):-
    H1 = H2,
    same(R1, R2).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not familiar with your code I rewrote it with similar functionality. Lines followed by `%here` are my improvements (2 times used). For simplicity I used the inbuild predicates `length/2` and `append/3` instead of `add/3`. `sublist/3` has a complete different code but same functionality, `same/2` is not necessary at all. Most uses of you `add/3` were not necessary as well as some equality statements.

```
most_common_sublist(L,N,Temp):-
    generator(L,N,LOP),
    check(LOP,_,Temp).

sublist(L,N,S):-
    length(S,N),
    append(S,_,L).

generator(L,N,[L]):-
    length(L,N).
generator([H|T],N,LOP):-
    sublist([H|T],N,PN),
    generator(T,N,LP),
    append([PN],LP,LOP).

check([],0,[]).
check([H|T],N,H):-
    check_how_many(H,[H|T],N),
    check(T,P,_),
    N>=P.
check([H|T],P,Temp):-
    check_how_many(H,[H|T],N),
    check(T,P,Temp)
%here
    , N=<P
    .

check_how_many(X,[X],1).
check_how_many(_,[_],0).
check_how_many(H,[H|T],Hits):-
    check_how_many(H,T,P),
    Hits is P+1.
check_how_many(Pattern,[H|T],P):-
%here
    Pattern \== H,
    check_how_many(Pattern,T,P).
```

After giving up on tracing I just used the following call to debug after enabling long output (
`?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(100)]).`
):

```
?- findall(Temp,check([[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1]],_,Temp),Out).
```

Initial output was

```
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,1],[],[],[2,2,1],[2,2,1],[],[]].
```

Which contains way to much empty lists. First fix (`%here`) was to set the condition `N=<P` for the last `check/3` case. Until now it was possible to choose a `P` lower than `N`, which should be covered by the 2nd `check/3` case. Output changed to

```
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,1],[2,2,1],[]].
```

Better, but still empty lists possible. A similar case happens in the last `check_how_many/3` case: you have to state that `H` and `Pattern` are different, otherwise it would be possible for a fitting `Pattern` not to be counted. Lets check the output

```
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,1]].
```

Way better. Lets check another case:

```
?- findall(Temp,check([[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1]],_,Temp),Out).
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]].

?- findall(Temp,check([[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]],_,Temp),Out).
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[1,2,2]].
```

Works... Almost.

So the problem seems to be `check_how_many/3`: alter

```
check_how_many(_,[_],0).
```

to

```
check_how_many(_,[],0).
```

and you should be fine.

```
?- findall(Temp,check([[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]],_,Temp),Out).
Out = [[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]].
```

Since it is way more fun to write the code yourself than to debug foreign code I'll add another answer with my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It is way more fun to code by yourself than to debug alien code. So here is my attempt. It works different than yours because I do not calculate possible subsets but work on the "leftover" list. I use the inbuild predicates `length/2`, `append/3` and `member/2` which are 3 lines each to write down.

```
% check how often 2.nd attribute List occurs in 1st attribute List.
countit([],_,Val,Val). 
countit([H|In],Out,Past,Future):-
    (   append(Out,_,[H|In])
    ->  Present is Past+1,
        countit(In,Out,Present,Future)
    ;   countit(In,Out,Past,Future)
    ).
    
mostCommonSublist(In,N,Out):-
    maxStartList(In,N,OutList,Max),
    member((Max,Out),OutList).

% for every endlist calculate how often the first N elements appear within the endlist, track the max
maxStartList(In,N,[(1,In)],1):-
    length(In,N),
    !.
maxStartList([H|In],N,[(CntH,Curr)|MaxList],Max):-
    length(Curr,N),
    countit([H|In],Curr,0,CntH),
    maxStartList(In,N,MaxList,CntIn),
    Max is max(CntH , CntIn).
```

The main predicate `mostCommonSublist/3` calls the predicate `maxStartList/4` to get all sublists/countpairs. Afterwards it validates if the count of a sublist equals the maximum. This is neccessary to check for different answers with the same (maximum) count.

The `maxStartList/4` drops elements from the inputlist and counts how often the start of the current list occurs within it. Also it keeps track of the maximum.

For the current inputlist the calculating predicate `countit/4` is called. It calculated for a given inputlist (first argument) the number of occurences of a sublist (2nd argument).
My code actually uses a twist: The content of the sublist is not unified when calling `countit/4` for the first time, just the sublist length is set. In the first recursion it will unify all entries with the start elements from the inputlist and count it. In the following recursion steps the sublist if fully known. Using an if-then-else `(..->..;..)` the two cases for remaining inputlist starts with the sublist or not, the predicate basically counts the occurences. Until the remaining inputlist has only `N` elements left (`length(In,N)`).

The calculated count/sublist pairs are stored in a list, the maximum is tracked as well.

After knowing all count/sublist pairs I finallize it all by stating that the count of an accepted sublist has to be equal to the maximum.

The nice thing is that there are no dublicate answers.

```
?- mostCommonSublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],3,L).
L = [2,2,3] ;
false.

?- mostCommonSublist([1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,3],3,L).
L = [1,2,2] ;
L = [2,1,2] ;
false.

?- mostCommonSublist([1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1],2,L).
L = [1,2] ;
L = [2,2] ;
L = [2,1] ;
false.
```